# How to display category name on cart page in Magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to display the product category on cart page but it returns empty array.
The file which i use is
`/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php`

My code is

```
public function getCustumcatId(){
    $proid=$this->getProduct()->getId();
    $mproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($proid);
    $ids=$this->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();
    return $ids;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Product can be assigned to many categories, so without significant modification you may not be able to find out which category that product came from, however this might be able to do what you're after from that class:

```
<?php

$_catCollection = $this->getItem()->getProduct()->getCategoryCollection();

foreach ($_catCollection as $_category) {
  // do stuff with your Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After number of trial and errors finally i have answer of question. And I want to share it.. I hope it helps someone..

Copy `/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php` to `/app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php` and make this change:

```
public function getCustumcatId()
{
    $proid=$this->getProduct()->getId();
    $categoryIds=$this->getProduct()->getCategoryIds($proid);
    foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId)
    {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    }
    return  $category->getName();
}
```

And for display category name on Cart page
open `/app/design/frontend/em0014/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.php`
near line no.36

```
<?php 
    $mycat_name=$this->htmlEscape($this->getCustumcatId());
    echo "Categoryid".$mycat_name."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've made one correction to your answer because it's a bad idea to make changes to core files. Instead, copy the file to `local` and make the change there. Also please tick the checkmark beside your answer to show others that it is the correct one.

Comment: Hi,Clockworkgeek ,
You are correct ,making changes in core files is not a good practice.we can place all file in local folders

Comment: That's still bad practice.  You should learn how to do rewrites.  It makes your code much cleaner.