# Displaying category name in the cart page

Tags: php, magento

I am new to magento and i am using magento 1.7.Now i am stuck up with a problem of displaying category name in the cart page. i have used following method to display category name
[How to display category name on cart page in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543375/how-to-display-category-name-on-cart-page-in-magento)
But if the product is assigned to multiple category it is taking product assigned with the last category(category name).I want to display from category name from which it is added to cart. Please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

hi there is no way you can check from which category the product is added to the cart.

Either you have to display all categories associated with that product else you need to add a custom table and create a add_to_cart observer and insert entries into it using observers.

Ref below :

[Add extra item to the cart (observer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856984/add-extra-item-to-the-cart-observer)

Note : you can use quote_id of order in the above table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to display category on cart page....

```
<?php

$_catCollection = $this->getItem()->getProduct()->getCategoryCollection();

foreach ($_catCollection as $_category) {
    echo $catName = $_category->getName();
}
?>
```